# substring causing Index and length must refer to a location within the string error?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to log errors that may happened within my application and insert it into oracle database as below, but I am getting error at `substring` that says

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

```
catch (Exception EX)
{
    string ErrorMsg = EX.Message.Substring(1, 1024);

    Error_log(ErrorMsg, null, "InsertProductData", "F0103", null);
    MessageBox.Show("Please call technical support", "ُError Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

anyone can help please ? is there more infroamtion I can save too ? anyway to extract error code ? not only the error message ?

**Sutloion Feedback**

Thank you all ..
just want to give feedback for other on how solved issue like this 
I solved by using below code

```
string ErrorMsg = ex.Message.Substring(0, Math.Min(ex.Message.Length, 1024));
```

Comment: what is the length of "EX.Message"?

Comment: @imsome1 I just want the first 1024 character which is the maximum size of column so I am string the substring from position zero to 1024

Comment: try 0 to 1023 and see

Comment: @imsome1 I tried before posting and tried from 1 to 1023

Comment: There are many cases in programming where the error messages that we receive are cryptic and we have no option but go to stackoverflow for help.  This isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `EX.Message.Substring(1, 1024)` to `EX.Message.Substring(1,Math.Min(Ex.Message.Length - 1,1024))`

Comment: Why not include the 0th `char`?

Comment: There is no special reason.  he started from 1

Comment: @levent NO exception no error and nothing happend